# Issue with Tkinter and GUI size

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

does anyone know how to make to keep the size of the window? As you can see, whenever I choose a file, the file path will change the GUI size:

[image]

[image]

Im not sure if you can see the images of the GUI but the path string will just make the window wider.

I´ll leave you the code below. The Frame I am having issues with is the "file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Open File", padx=6, pady=6, bg="Gainsboro")" one

```
# initalize the tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()

root.configure(bg='Gainsboro')
root.resizable(0, 0) # makes the root window fixed in size.

root.title("Metadata Population")

#########################################################################
##################### Add ExxonMobil Logo to the title ##################
#########################################################################

root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\SCDBOHU\Desktop\GitRepos\SeismicDataAutomation\Project\GUI\EM_Logo.ico")

#########################################################################
##################### Make the console textbox ##########################
#########################################################################

tk.text = Text(root)
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.config (command=tk.text.yview)
tk.text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
tk.text.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        

tk.text.insert(tk.END, "Python Version : " + sys.version)  # write text to textbox
tk.text.see(END)


#########################################################################
##################### Add title label ###################################
#########################################################################

Label(root, text="Metadata Automation", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 16").pack(pady=15, padx=6, side=TOP)


#########################################################################
##################### Create frames #####################################
#########################################################################

file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Open File", padx=6, pady=6, bg="Gainsboro")
file_frame.pack(expand = False, fill="both")

checkboxes_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Population options", padx=6, pady=6, bg="Gainsboro")
checkboxes_frame.pack(expand = True, fill="both")


#########################################################################
############### Add buttons and checkboxes to the frames ################
#########################################################################

# The file/file path text
label_file = tk.Label(file_frame, text="No File Selected", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 8")
label_file.pack(padx=5, pady=20)

# Add the "BROWSE A FILE" button
button1 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Browse A File", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 8", command=lambda: File_dialog())
button1.pack(padx=5, pady=20)

Print1 = tk.Label(file_frame, text="*The program only accepts .xls and .xlsx", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 7")
Print1.pack(padx=0, pady=20)



#Make checkboxes
survey = tk.IntVar()
project = tk.IntVar()


SurveyCheckbox = Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text="Insert a survey", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 10", variable=survey, onvalue=1, offvalue=3)
ProjectCheckbox = Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text="Insert a project", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 10", variable=project, onvalue=2, offvalue=4)
SurveyCheckbox.pack(padx=5, pady=20)
ProjectCheckbox.pack(padx=5, pady=20)
Print2 = tk.Label(checkboxes_frame, text="*Select what you would like to insert", bg="Gainsboro", font = "Verdana 7")
Print2.pack(padx=0, pady=20)

SurveyCheckbox.deselect()
ProjectCheckbox.deselect()


#Add submit button
Button(root, text="Submit", width= 10, height=3, bg="LightSlateGray", fg="WHITE", font = "Verdana 10", command=lambda: Gui()).pack(padx=0, pady=20)

#########################################################################
##################### Create and load the files #########################
#########################################################################

def File_dialog():
    #This Function will open the file explorer and assign the chosen file path to label_file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                          title="Select A File",
                                          filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),("All Files", "*.*")))
    filesplit = filename.split("/")[-1]
    
    label_file["text"] = filename
    
    return filename
  
def Load_excel_data():

    #If the file selected is valid this will load the file into the Treeview
    file_path = label_file["text"]
    
    try:

        file = r"{}".format(file_path)
        
        if file[-4:] == ".csv":
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='xlrd')

        else:
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='openpyxl')
        
    except ValueError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None

    except FileNotFoundError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None
    
    return df

#########################################################################
########## Create a function to close de GUI window #####################
#########################################################################
def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "Do you want to exit?"):
        root.destroy()

#########################################################################
##################### Create the GUI logic ##############################
#########################################################################

def Gui():

    tk.text.tag_configure('success', foreground='green')
    tk.text.tag_configure('information', foreground='blue')
    tk.text.tag_configure('error', foreground='red')
    
    survey_chk = survey.get()
    project_chk = project.get()
    
    df = Load_excel_data()

    connection = utils.CreateConnection()

    try:

        if survey_chk == 1 and project_chk != 2:
            utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            
        
        elif project_chk == 2 and survey_chk != 1:
            utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
        
        elif survey_chk == 1 and project_chk == 2:
            utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
    
    except Exception as e:
        tk.text.insert(tk.END, "Something went wrong:", 'error')
        tk.text.insert(tk.END, e, 'error')
        tk.text.see(END)
    
    else:
        tk.text.insert(tk.END, "\n The upload was successful. You can close the window now\n", 'success')
        tk.text.see(END)

        



#########################################################################
##################### Create the console printer logic ##################
#########################################################################

class PrintLogger(): # create file like object

    def __init__(self, textbox): # pass reference to text widget
        tk.textbox = textbox # keep ref

    def write(self, text):

        try:
            if (text[0] == "#") :
                tk.textbox.insert(tk.END, text[1:], ('important'))  # write text to textbox
                tk.textbox.tag_configure ('important', foreground = 'blue')

            else :
                tk.textbox.insert(tk.END, text)  # write text to textbox

            tk.textbox.see(END)
            tk.textbox.update_idletasks()
            sys.stdout.flush()

        except IndexError:
            tk.textbox.insert(tk.END, text)
        except Exception as e :
            #self.master.destroy()
            sys.exit()

#########################################################################
#################### Code to start the Metadata Populator ###############
#########################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create a protocol when closing the window
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()
    utils.ConnectionInit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root,width=a,height=b ,text="Open File", padx=6, pady=6, bg="Gainsboro")
file_frame.pack_propagate(False)
file_frame.pack(expand = False, fill="both")
```

Where a,b is the dimensions for the frame(You should calculate it to match it)
and `.pack_propagate(False)` prevents the labelFrame from changing its sizes

Actually, you do not need the `width` and `height`, you can let it be default size by just not specifiying it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this but the frame just disappeared

Comment: Then specify the width and height like `width=50,height=50`. I do not know the exact value tho. You will need to calculate

Comment: There we go, with the width and height worked great. Thanks a lot!!